# How to use different SOCKS proxy for different CLI apps?

Tags: command-line, socks

based on some politics I cannot use proxychains* utilites ( no preload accepted ). As I understood is no chance to achieve it using sandboxes and no netspaces yet in OSX. I can play with the firewall little bit, but it looks complicated. Is there a way to redirect all traffic to the SOCKS proxy per specified cli app?

Comment: Netspace = network namespace?

Comment: yes, like linux

Comment: Which cli commands? Some will use env vars for proxy config. Your best bet here is probably a virtual machine...

Comment: Yes, that what I doing right now, a linux virtual machine. But it looks little bit heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [TS-Warp](https://github.com/mezantrop/ts-warp), works natively on macOS, Linux, BSD. CLI and graphical apps, no SIP disabling, no KEXT installation on fresh macOS. It uses Firewall/NAT redirection instead of library preloading, so this plays the trick for macos with strict rules against preloaded libraries.

Comment: Right now this reads like an ad. Can you improve your anwer by showing *how* the tool you recommend can be used to solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: @nohillside, this should solve the issue, correct? :)